# "dojo AMD format, makes code easier to author and debug", how to prove it?

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd

Dojo said that "dojo AMD format, makes code easier to author and debug"
(https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules_advanced/)

is there any one can show us an example code to prove this statement?
tanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMD allows division/organization of your code in modules, which are loaded on demand, this have some advantages:

- Organization: You code tend to be more structured and organized when you think in term of modules.
- Debug: As you code is separated in functionalities/feature per module it simplifies debugging as the amount of code for a module is more limited in length and scope.
- Testing: It is more easy to organize your test cases when your code it is well defined in separate modules.

More information about [AMD and module](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules/).

Example of simple module for a navbar:

```
// in "my/widget/NavBar.js"
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dojo/text!./templates/NavBar.html"
], function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, template){
    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
        // template contains the content of the file "my/widget/templates/NavBar.html"
        templateString: template
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Gibbonk.... :)  may us get an example code for your answer ? thanks a lot

Comment: @riobmunas yes off-course, I made an edit to my answer.

Comment: @riobmunas If you found my answer useful, please do not forget to upvote/accept it using the icons on its left side. More info here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work  Thanks and happy coding! ;)

Comment: ok thanks GibboK....